# Android: switching from two-pane (landscape) layout to single-pane (portrait) layout, how do I handle the switching of list and detail fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Background and Intro**

My app consists of a single activity and 3 fragments. The app is viewed in two-panes only for 600dp smallest width in landscape only.  In Portrait orientation it is viewed in a single pane nor matter which size.

Heres an overview of what it looks like.

SINGLE PANE MODE

[image]

TWO PANE MODE

[image]

Quick description of what this app does. In single pane mode fragmentAList is added to a container (R.id.list_container). When an item is pressed, its container is replaced with fragmentBDetail which contains a description and a button. Pressing this button goes to FragmentC. FragmentBDetail and FragmentC are added to back stack so the user can navigate back to FragmentAList.

In two pane mode, there are two containers (R.id.list_container) and (R.id.detail_container). 
FragmentAList still goes inside R.id.list_container but clicking an item shows FragmentBDetail inside R.id.detail_container on the same screen.

**The Problem I am having**

I want to be able to go from two-pane mode to single pane when the orientation changes while maintaining the detail fragment. i.e. If the user was in two-pane mode and they clicked an item in the list to see the detail (say the Windows description) and when they switch to portrait orientation (single pane) I want the detail fragment (Windows description) to be shown in the single pane.

Likewise, if it was in single pane, and the user clicked a list item to see its detail. I want that detail fragment to be shown in second pane when the orientation changes to landscape.

At the current moment, if I am in two-pane mode and I switch orientation to single pane, I will see FragmentAList only. If I then click a list item I see FragmentAlist replaced with FragmentBDetail. If I then change orientation to two-pane mode, I will see two FragmentBDetails.

**What I have tried**

I am absolutely clueless on this problem and not sure what to do. All I have got at the moment is the tag of the fragment that is inside the detail_cotainer. With this tag I am able to find the fragment.

```
if(mIsTwoPane)
        {
            Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_container);

            if(frag != null)
            {
                Log.d("TEST", "found something = " + frag.getTag());

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("TEST", "nothing");
            }
        }
```

**My Code**

Below is what I deem the major parts of the code. Please let me know if you want to see others.

**Main Activity**

Here I am checking if I am in two pane mode. Also I add FragmentAList into the R.id.list_container (which will always be there)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null)
        {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            FragmentAList fragmentAList = new FragmentAList();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.list_container, fragmentAList, FragmentAList.class.getName());
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    }
```

**FragmentAList**

Here I get the value of mTwoPane from MainActivity. if its true, I set a variable to the ID of detail_container. If its false, I set to the ID of the R.id.list_container (which will always be there).

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        mIsTwoPane = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getIsTwoPane();

        if(mIsTwoPane)
        {
            containerID = R.id.detail_container;
        }
        else
        {
            containerID = container.getId();
        }

        lvPlatforms = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvPlatforms);

        return view;

    }
```

This is used here within the onItemClickListener for the List View. the ContainerID variable contains the ID of the container based on the logic seen above in onCreateView. Also if its not in two pane mode I don't add to back stack only if its not two-pane (so the user can navigate back to the list view)

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) 
    {


        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerID, FragmentBDetail.newInstance(pos), FragmentBDetail.class.getName());
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

        if(!mIsTwoPane) //NOT in two pane mode
        {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
```

Thank you for reading.